# Spark Dataset appending unique ID

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm looking whether there is an "already implemented alternative" to `append` unique ID on a spark dataset.

My scenario:
I have an incremental job that runs each day processing a batch of information. In this job, I create a dimension table of `something` and assign unique IDs to each row using `monotonically_increasing_id()`. On next day, I want to append some rows to that `something` table and want to generate unique IDs for those rows.

Example:

day 1:

```
something_table    
uniqueID   name
100001     A
100002     B
```

day 2:

```
something_table
uniqueId   name
100001     A
100002     B
100003     C -- new data that must be created on day 2
```

Sniped code for day 1:

```
case class BasicSomething(name: String)
case class SomethingTable(id: Long, name: String)

val ds: Dataset[BasicSomething] = spark.createDataset(Seq(BasicSomething("A"), BasicSomething("B")))

ds.withColumn("uniqueId", monotonically_increasing_id())
.as[SomethingTable]
.write.csv("something")
```

I have no idea of how to keep state for `monotonically_increasing_id()` in a way that in the next day it will know the existing ids from `something_table` unique id.

Comment: There is official "already implemented alternative" and if there is any other, recommendations are off-topic. Also "Keeping state" doesn't sound like such a good idea, as upper bits are already utilized so amount of information you can keep is limited. If you're set on `Long` you can use `zipWithIndex` with offset based on existing data. Better us ID, which can be created in place like tuple (batch, monotonically_increasing_id).

Comment: @user6910411 what do you mean by "Keeping state doesn't sound like such a good idea"? how would references work if there are no fixed ids?

Comment: @MehdiB. I guess it wasn't very clear.  So the main problem, as already stated, is that the upper 31 bits are already used by the partition number. So only a very small fraction of the 64 bits can be actually used in practice or in other words you already start with very large number  if you have more than one partition, and adding anything to it, is not a greatest idea. There many robust schemes that allow you to generate unique identifiers in distributed systems, without keeping state - see for example MongoDB object ids.

Comment: Thank you for the response @user6910411

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always get the *last uniqueId* of a *dataset* that you have created.  Thus you can **use that uniqueId with monotically_increasing_id() and create new uniqueIds**.

```
ds.withColumn("uniqueId", monotonically_increasing_id()+last uniqueId of previous dataframe)
```

Comment: Can we extend this  solution to scenario where batches are running concurrently?  e.g last persisted unique id is 1. Two or more batches running simultaneously will get this same id i.e. 1. Now both batch1 and batch2 will start generating the new ids starting from 2 which is not desired.